# Why can't I have a rank index without duplicate values

Tags: indexing, powerbi, dax, group

I created a rank with this code

```
RANK = RANKX(FILTER(
    'Table',
    'Table'[ID]= EARLIER('Table'[ID]) &&
        'Table'[Date Time] < EARLIER('Table'[Date Time])
),'Table'[Date Time],,ASC,Skip)
```

which to some extent worked and followed the proper order but it gave me 1,1,1,4 instead of 1,2,3,4. The Date and Time is the same for the first three rows. Next thing I did was add a column with random values.

```
SupportingColumn = RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTROWS('Table'))
```

I was hoping that I could still do the same grouping but sort it by some index cause it doesn't matter which row is before the other. However it completely disorigented my position.

```
RANK = RANKX(FILTER(
    'Table',
    'Table'[ID]= EARLIER('Table'[ID]) &&
        'Table'[Date Time] < EARLIER('Table'[Date Time])
),'Table'[SupportingColumn],,ASC,Skip)
```

same code as before but now completely placing the values all over the place. Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sorting 'Table'[Date Time] directly sort by this **calculated column**:

```
Sort Column = DATEDIFF ( DATE ( 1970, 1, 1 ), 'Table'[Date Time], SECOND ) + RAND() / 10
```

Basically this converts 'Table'[Date Time] into Unix Seconds and then adds a random number between 0 and 0.1

Comment: I created the sort column and referenced it in the RANKX argument but it still gave me 1,1,1,4. ```RANK = RANKX(FILTER('Table','Table'[ID]= EARLIER('Table'[ID]) && 'Table'[Date Time] < EARLIER('Table'[Date Time])
),'Table'[Sort Column],,ASC,Skip)```

Comment: Ok nevermind instead I did ```RANK = RANKX(FILTER('Table','Table'[ID]= EARLIER('Table'[ID]) ,'Table'[Sort Column],,ASC,Skip)```. It worked. Thank you.